cryptsetup unlock skips pressed keys - first attempt fails
I have a strange problem. When I try to unlock my LUKS volume at boot, the first unlock attempt almost always fails, even though I enter the correct password.
It turns out some key presses are not registered, a few characters that I type in are dropped. This can be verified by observing the asterisks that appear when pressing the keys. As time passes, less and less characters are missing, but it can happen even after 10-15 seconds. Doesn't help if I type the characters slowly, one-by-one.
I have a new MSI Thin GF63 12VF laptop (NVIDIA graphics) with a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04. Maybe the hardware is too new for the OS?
I tried a few things to verify it's a hardware problem with the built-in keyboard:

I didn't experience the problem with an attached USB keyboard.
However, the built-in keyboard works perfectly to enter the BIOS password - just a few seconds after power on.
GRUB is also able to correctly initialize the built-in keyboard before the unlock screen. So the keyboard normally doesn't need time to "warm up".
I can wait a minute in GRUB, then boot into Ubuntu. When I get to the unlock screen, the built-in keyboard is again unreliable for the same 10-15 seconds.
If I boot to the initramfs shell (append a break keyword to the linux line in GRUB), the same thing happens as on the unlock screen. So it may be related to initramfs.
I'm not sure how keyboard input is handled here, but this might help: when I simply long press a key, it still drops characters: the stream of new characters skips a beat every now and then. A "key up event" is never missed, as no new characters appear after I release a key.

I don't know if it's related to the graphics card. The same happens with the XOrg Nouveau driver, I tried the nomodeset and intermap=off cmdline parameters to no avail.
This behavior is quite annoying when I want to boot into my system quickly. Anyone can help me debug/solve or work around the problem? Thank you!
Edit.
I changed MODULES=most to MODULES=dep in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf. This way the problem's only present for a second, and no keys are missed after. But this also makes the computer freeze on the unlock screen quite often. This was only one of the many problems I had with my MSI laptop, so I decided to return it and buy one from a more reliable brand.

@user68186 Thank you, an external keyboard works fine. I still don't think it's purely a hardware issue. I edited the question.

@user68186 I had a brand new install of Ubuntu 22.04 (also tried 24.04). I don't think there is any point in recreating the initramfs. Anyways, I decided not to keep this notebook.

Thanks for telling me. Please delete the question.

I have the same problem with MSI Raider GE77. I think it's related to steelseries aps alx/klc
